# iOS and OpenPay payment getting called twice

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, payment

My issue is here, I have a controller where a charge is supposed to get done. But some how is getting called twice and the error form OpenPay is very non-informative. I'm using parse cloud code in back4app moved the called function around make it background and main threads but still I'm getting the same error in my code. I see it only called once but I'm tired and of course overlooking something. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Payment view controller code:

```
//
//  DatosTarjetaViewController.swift
//  Automozo2
//
//  Created by Pedro Alonso on 17/02/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Pedro Alonso. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Parse
//import Openpay
import ReachabilitySwift
import CircularSpinner

class DatosTarjetaViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, CircularSpinnerDelegate {

    //Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    @IBOutlet weak var cardNumberField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var CVCField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var monthField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var yearField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var LastNameField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var realizarPedidoBtn: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var totalLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var recordarSwitch: UISwitch!

    //Parse data
    var numeroExterior: String!
    var numeroDeTelefono: String!
    var lavadoCarro: String!
    var lavadoMiniVan: String!
    var lavadoPickUp: String!
    var lavadoDeVan: String!

    var lavadoAspiradoCarro: String!
    var lavadAspiradoMiniVan: String!
    var lavadoAspiradoPickUp: String!
    var lavadoAspiradoDeVan: String!

    var monto: String!

    var location: PFGeoPoint!
    var errorInPayment: Bool = false
    var stopSpinner: Bool = false


    //Timers as needeor used
    var checkInternetTimer: Timer!
    var timerSpinner: Timer!
    var timerMakeStopSpinner: Timer!
    var timerShowMapa: Timer!



    //Data vars
    var fechaRegistro: String!
    var totalString: String!
    var locationOrder: PFGeoPoint!

    //data from user
    var cardNumber: String!
    var nameUser: String!
    var expiryMonth: String!
    var expiryYear: String!
    var CVC: String!
    var alertaDataNotSaved: Bool = true

    //extra vars
    var token: Token? = nil

    //open pay things
    var openPayConExtra = Openpay(merchantId: "mi4yferqt4ib09rporb9", apyKey: "pk_4e4d1675c7a34846a27f52b8c8bcbe73", isProductionMode: false, isDebug: true)
    var openPayToken: OPToken! {
        didSet {
            let sessionId = self.openPayConExtra!.createDeviceSessionId()
//            self.makeCardPayment(tokenId: self.openPayToken.id!, amount: self.totalString!, deviceSessionId: sessionId!, name: self.nameUser!, lastName: self.nameUser!, phoneNumber: self.numeroDeTelefono!)
        }
    }
    let orderId: String = "\(arc4random())"

    //user defaults to save data
    var savedDataOfCard: UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

    //Errores
    var jumpToSegue: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if jumpToSegue != true {

                self.successSegue()
            } else {

            }

        }
    }

    var error: NSError = NSError() {
        didSet {
            if (error as NSError).code != 0 {
                self.errorAlert(error: self.error)



            } else {


            }
                    }
    }

    var endSpinner: Bool! {
        didSet {
            CircularSpinner.hide()
            self.displayError2(error: "Error", message: "Hubo un error al tratar con tu tarjeta, por favor intenta de nuevo.")

        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        //button look
        self.realizarPedidoBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        self.realizarPedidoBtn.layer.borderWidth = 3
        self.realizarPedidoBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        self.realizarPedidoBtn.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0
        self.realizarPedidoBtn.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        self.realizarPedidoBtn.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)

        //------------------------------------------------//



        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        //Scroll stuff to dismiss the keyboard
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(DatosTarjetaViewController.keyboardWillShow(notification:)),
            name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow,
            object: nil
        )
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(DatosTarjetaViewController.keyboardWillHide(notification:)),
            name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide,
            object: nil
        )

        scrollView.delegate = self

        scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissMode.interactive

        let touch = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(DatosTarjetaViewController.singleTapGestureCaptured(gesture:)))
        scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(touch)


        checkInternetTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 4, target: self, selector: #selector(checkInternetStatus), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        if savedDataOfCard.object(forKey: "cardNumber") == nil {


        } else {

         self.timerSpinner = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60, target: self, selector: #selector(checkTimerSpinner), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

         self.timerMakeStopSpinner = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval:20, target: self, selector: #selector(makeTrueStopSpinner), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }



        self.cardNumberField.delegate = self


    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        self.totalLabel.text = self.totalString

        if savedDataOfCard.object(forKey: "switch") != nil {

            self.fillSavedData()
        } else {

            self.clearAll()
        }

        if alertaDataNotSaved {

            self.displayError2(error: "Atencion", message: "Nosotros no grabamos tu informacion, solo tu celular. La pasamos directo al servidor.")
            alertaDataNotSaved = false
        }

    }

    func makeTrueStopSpinner() {

        if !stopSpinner {

            self.stopSpinner = true

        } else  {

            self.stopSpinner = false
        }
    }

    func checkTimerSpinner() {

        if self.stopSpinner == true {

            CircularSpinner.hide()
            self.timerSpinner.invalidate()

            self.displayError2(error: "Error", message: "El servidor ha tardado mucho en responder, por favor intenta mas tarde.")
        } else {


            self.stopSpinner = true
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //MARK:- Actions to perform
    @IBAction func regresarTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

        self.clearAll()
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func clearAll() {

        self.cardNumberField.text = ""
        self.LastNameField.text = ""
        self.monthField.text = ""
        self.CVCField.text = ""
        self.nameField.text = ""
        self.yearField.text = ""

        self.recordarSwitch.isOn = false


    }

    @IBAction func realizarPedidoTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if cardNumberField.text!.characters.count >= 15 && nameField.text! != "" && monthField.text!.characters.count == 2 && yearField.text!.characters.count == 2 && LastNameField.text! != "" && CVCField.text!.characters.count >= 3  {

            self.getDataFromUser()
            self.fechaRegistro = self.getDateString()

            self.displayError(error: "Alerta", message: "Estas seguro que quieres mandar el pago?")


        } else {

            self.displayError2(error: "Error", message: "Has ingresado mal un dato, por favor revisalos")
        }


    }

    @IBAction func switchTapped(_ sender: UISwitch) {

        if sender.isOn && self.chechNotEmptyFields() {

            self.savedData()
        } else {

            self.removeData()

            self.clearAll()
        }
    }

    func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification){

        var userInfo = notification.userInfo!
        var keyboardFrame:CGRect = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        keyboardFrame = self.view.convert(keyboardFrame, from: nil)

        var contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = self.scrollView.contentInset
        contentInset.bottom = keyboardFrame.size.height
        self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInset
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(notification:NSNotification){

        let contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInset
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)

    }

    func singleTapGestureCaptured(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        self.view.endEditing(true)

    }

    func getDataFromUser() {

        self.cardNumber = self.cardNumberField.text!
        self.nameUser = self.nameField.text! + " " + self.LastNameField.text!
        self.expiryMonth = self.monthField.text!
        self.expiryYear = self.yearField.text!
        self.CVC = self.CVCField.text!


    }

    //MARK: - Here call this when server is done
    func makeCardPayment(tokenId: String, description: String = "Lavado de autos a domicilio.", amount: String, deviceSessionId: String, name: String, lastName: String, phoneNumber: String, email: String = "pruebas@automozo.com.mx") -> Bool {


        var card: OPCard = OPCard()
            var nameToSend = nameUser.components(separatedBy: " ")

        do {

          let result = try PFCloud.callFunction("hello", withParameters: ["tokenId":tokenId , "description": description , "amount":Double(amount)! ,"deviceSessionId":deviceSessionId , "name": nameToSend[0], "lastName":nameToSend[1] , "phoneNumber":numeroDeTelefono! , "email": email,  "orderId":"\(arc4random())"])
            print(result)

        } catch let error {

            print("error here: \(error)")
        }

        return true
    }

    func createToken() {

        let card = OPCard()
        card.holderName = self.nameUser!
        card.number = self.cardNumber!
        card.expirationMonth = self.expiryMonth!
        card.expirationYear = self.expiryYear!
        card.cvv2 = self.CVC!

        var opToken: OPToken!

        print("nombre: \(self.nameUser!) card: \(self.cardNumber!) epxMonth: \(self.expiryMonth!) year: \(self.expiryYear!) cvv2: \(self.CVC!)")
        var sessionId = self.openPayConExtra?.createDeviceSessionId()

        print(card)
        self.openPayConExtra!.createToken(with: card, success: {
            token -> Void in

            print("the token: \(token!)")
            self.openPayToken = token!

        }, failure: {
            error -> Void in

            print("the error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
            self.endSpinner = true


        })

    }

    func savedData() {

        self.getDataFromUser()

        savedDataOfCard.set(self.cardNumber!, forKey: "cardNumber")
        savedDataOfCard.set(self.nameUser!, forKey: "nameUser")
        savedDataOfCard.set(self.expiryMonth!, forKey: "expirationMonth")
        savedDataOfCard.set(self.expiryYear!, forKey: "expirationYear")
        savedDataOfCard.set(self.CVC!, forKey: "cvc")

        savedDataOfCard.set(true, forKey: "switch")

        savedDataOfCard.synchronize()
    }

    func removeData() {

        savedDataOfCard.removeObject(forKey: "cardNumber")
        savedDataOfCard.removeObject(forKey: "nameUser")
        savedDataOfCard.removeObject(forKey: "expirationMonth")
        savedDataOfCard.removeObject(forKey: "expirationYear")
        savedDataOfCard.removeObject(forKey: "cvc")

        savedDataOfCard.removeObject(forKey: "switch")


        savedDataOfCard.synchronize()





    }

    func chechNotEmptyFields() -> Bool {

        if self.cardNumberField.text! != "" && self.nameField.text! != "" && self.monthField.text! != "" && self.yearField.text! != "" && self.CVCField.text! != "" {

            return true
        } else {

            return false
        }
    }

    func fillSavedData() {

        var nameComponents = (self.savedDataOfCard.value(forKey: "nameUser") as! String).components(separatedBy: " ")

        self.cardNumberField.text = (self.savedDataOfCard.value(forKey: "cardNumber") as! String)
        self.nameField.text = nameComponents[0]
        self.LastNameField.text = nameComponents[1]
        self.monthField.text = (self.savedDataOfCard.value(forKey: "expirationMonth") as! String)
        self.yearField.text = (self.savedDataOfCard.value(forKey: "expirationYear") as! String)
        self.CVCField.text = (self.savedDataOfCard.value(forKey: "cvc") as! String)
        self.recordarSwitch.isOn = self.savedDataOfCard.bool(forKey: "switch")

    }



    func displayError(error: String, message: String) {

        let alert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: error, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { alert in


            CircularSpinner.show("Aguarda un momento...", animated: true, type: CircularSpinnerType.indeterminate, showDismissButton: true, delegate: self)

            self.createToken()


        })
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive, handler: {
            (alert) -> Void in

            self.clearAll()
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))

        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "MapaMozosSecondSegue" {

            var mapaMozosVC = segue.destination as! MapaMozosViewController

            mapaMozosVC.totalPrevious = self.totalString
            mapaMozosVC.fechaDisplay = self.fechaRegistro
            mapaMozosVC.nameUser = self.nameUser
            mapaMozosVC.phone = numeroDeTelefono
        }
    }

    func getDateString() -> String {

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd YYYY HH:mm"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
        self.fechaRegistro = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())

        return dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
    }

    func displayError2(error: String, message: String) {

        let alert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: error, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { alert in

        })
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func checkInternetStatus() {

        // check if we've got network connectivity
        var testNetwork = Reachability(hostname: "www.google.com")

        if let statusNet = testNetwork?.currentReachabilityStatus {


            if statusNet.description == "No Connection" {

                self.displayError2(error: "Error", message: "Se ha perdido la conexion a internet. Necesito WiFi/Datos para continuar.")
                self.realizarPedidoBtn.isEnabled = false


            } else {

                self.realizarPedidoBtn.isEnabled = true
                print("everything normal keep refreshing")
            }

        } else {

            print("This should not happen")

        }



    }

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {


        return true

    }

    func circularSpinnerTitleForValue(_ value: Float) -> NSAttributedString {

        let attString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\(Int(0.4 * 100))%")

        return attString
    }

    func errorAlert(error: Error) {

        CircularSpinner.hide()
        let description = "description"
        var code = 0
        let errorInfo = error as? NSError
        let userInfo = "UserInfo"
        var messageError = "Message"

        print(errorInfo?.code)
        print(errorInfo.debugDescription)

        if errorInfo!.debugDescription.contains("3001") {

            print("La tarjeta fue declinada.")
            code = 3001
            messageError = "La tarjeta fue declinada."

        } else if errorInfo!.debugDescription.contains("3002") {

            print("La tarjeta ha expirado.")
            code = 3002
            messageError = "La tarjeta ha expirado."

        } else if errorInfo!.debugDescription.contains("3003") {

            print("La tarjeta no tiene fondos suficientes.")
            code = 3003
            messageError = "La tarjeta no tiene fondos suficientes."

        } else if errorInfo!.debugDescription.contains("3004") {
            print("La tarjeta ha sido identificada como una tarjeta robada.")
            code = 3004
            messageError = "La tarjeta ha sido identificada como una tarjeta robada."

        } else if errorInfo!.debugDescription.contains("3005") {
            print("La tarjeta ha sido rechazada por el sistema antifraudes.")
            code = 3005
            messageError = "La tarjeta ha sido rechazada por el sistema antifraudes."

        } else if errorInfo!.debugDescription.contains("3006") {
            print("La operación no esta permitida para este cliente o esta transacción.")
            code = 3006
            messageError = "La operación no esta permitida para este cliente o esta transacción."

        } else if errorInfo!.debugDescription.contains("3007") {
            print("La tarjeta fue declinada.")
            code = 3007
            messageError = "La tarjeta fue declinada."

        } else if errorInfo!.debugDescription.contains("3008") {
            print("La tarjeta no es soportada en transacciones en línea.")
            code = 3008
            messageError = "La tarjeta no es soportada en transacciones en línea."

        } else if errorInfo!.debugDescription.contains("3009") {
            print("La tarjeta fue reportada como perdida.")
            code = 3009
            messageError = "La tarjeta fue reportada como perdida."

        } else if errorInfo!.debugDescription.contains("3010") {
            print("El banco ha restringido la tarjeta.")
            code = 3010
            messageError = "El banco ha restringido la tarjeta."

        }else if errorInfo!.debugDescription.contains("3011") {
            print("El banco ha solicitado que la tarjeta sea retenida. Contacte al banco.")
            code = 3011
            messageError = "El banco ha solicitado que la tarjeta sea retenida. Contacte al banco."

        }else if errorInfo!.debugDescription.contains("3012") {
            print("Se requiere solicitar al banco autorización para realizar este pago.")
            code = 3012
            messageError = "Se requiere solicitar al banco autorización para realizar este pago."

        } else {
            print("No es error de tarjeta. Error del servicio.")
            code = 9999
            messageError = "No es error de tarjeta. Error del servicio. \n \(errorInfo?.description ?? "Error nil")"
        }

        self.displayError2(error: "Error", message: "Hubo este error. \nCodigo: \(code). \n Mensage: \(messageError.description)")


    }

    func successSegue() {



        let usuarioPagado: PFObject = PFObject(className: "Ordenes")

        usuarioPagado["Ubicacion"] = self.location!
        //Lavado
        usuarioPagado["NumeroExterior"] = self.numeroExterior!
        usuarioPagado["NumeroDeTelefono"] = self.numeroDeTelefono!
        usuarioPagado["LavadoCarro"] = self.lavadoCarro!
        usuarioPagado["LavadoMiniVan"] = self.lavadoMiniVan!
        usuarioPagado["LavadoPickUp"] = self.lavadoPickUp!
        usuarioPagado["LavadoDeVan"] = self.lavadoDeVan!

        //Lavado y aspirado
        usuarioPagado["LavadoAspiradoCarro"] = self.lavadoAspiradoCarro!
        usuarioPagado["LavadoAspiradoMiniVan"] = self.lavadAspiradoMiniVan!
        usuarioPagado["LavadoAspiradoPickUp"] = self.lavadoAspiradoPickUp!
        usuarioPagado["LavadoAspiradoDeVan"] = self.lavadoAspiradoDeVan!
        usuarioPagado["Monto"] = "\(self.monto!)"
        usuarioPagado["NumeroDeTelefono"] = self.numeroDeTelefono!
        usuarioPagado["TipoDeCelular"] = "iPhone"
        usuarioPagado["FechaDeOrden"] = self.fechaRegistro!
        usuarioPagado["NombrePersona"] = self.nameUser

        usuarioPagado.saveInBackground {
            (success, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {

                print(error?.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                CircularSpinner.hide()

                print(success)
                if self.errorInPayment == true {

                    self.displayError2(error: "Error", message: "Hubo un error al procesar tu pago, intenta de nuevo.")

                } else {

                    CircularSpinner.hide()
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "MapaMozosSecondSegue", sender: self)
                }

            }
        }
        CircularSpinner.hide()
    }


}
```

The cloud function:

```
console.log("hello world");
// Requiring npm module

var Openpay = require('openpay');
var openpay = new Openpay('****','***');
// Producción
openpay.setProductionReady(false);

conekta.api_key = 'key_ddopziKwBLSrG1YMiyMnJA';
conekta.api_version = '2.0.0';

Parse.Cloud.define("hello", function(request, response){
var tokenId = request.params.tokenId;
var description = request.params.description;
var amount = request.params.amount;
var deviceSessionId = request.params.deviceSessionId;
var name = request.params.name;
var lastName = request.params.lastName;
var phoneNumber = request.params.phoneNumber;
var email = request.params.email;
var orderId = request.params.orderId;

//openpay charge
var chargeRequest = {
   'source_id' : tokenId,
   'method' : 'card',
   'amount' : amount,
   'order_id': orderId,
   'currency' : 'MXN',
   'description' : description,
   'device_session_id' : deviceSessionId,
   'customer' : {
        'name' : name,
        'last_name' : lastName,
        'phone_number' : phoneNumber,
        'email' : email
   }
};

console.log(" " + "newCharge\n" + chargeRequest + "\n chargeRequest ");
openpay.charges.create(chargeRequest, function(error, charge) {
  // ...
  if (error) {
    console.log("error=" + error + " Descripcion:" + error.description + " error_code:" + error.error_code ); 
   response.error(error);
   } else {
   console.log("charge = " + charge);
   response.success();
   }


});




console.log("finish");
});
```

Comment: Can you please paste here the cloud code logs?

Comment: I have fixed it. Thanks Davi.